# Click default QPushButton when Enter SpinBox

Tags: c++, qt, button, click, default

I need to raise the click signal of my `QPushButton` when I press Enter on `QSpinBox` (actually on every input box), but even if my button is the default button, the following code doesn't work.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSpinBox>
#include <QMessageBox>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QWidget* window = new QWidget();

  QSpinBox* spinbox = new QSpinBox();
  QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Ok");
  button->setDefault(true);

  QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, []()
  { 
    QMessageBox::question(nullptr, "Test", "Quit?", QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
  });

  QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout();
  layout->addWidget(spinbox);
  layout->addWidget(button);
  window->setLayout(layout);
  window->show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see in the Qt documentation about [QPushButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#default-prop) :

> The default button behavior is provided only in dialogs

You are using a `QWidget` and expect the default button behavior to work. Just use a `QDialog` instead of `QWidget` :

```
QDialog * window = new QDialog();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html)

> The `QObject::installEventFilter()` function enables this by setting up
>   an event filter, causing a nominated filter object to receive the
>   events for a target object in its `QObject::eventFilter()` function. An
>   event filter gets to process events before the target object does,
>   allowing it to inspect and discard the events as required.

```
void QObject::installEventFilter ( QObject * filterObj )
```

Installs an event filter filterObj on this object. For example:

```
 monitoredObj->installEventFilter(filterObj);
```

> An event filter is an object that receives all events that are sent to
>   this object. The filter can either stop the event or forward it to
>   this object. The event filter filterObj receives events via its
>   eventFilter() function. The eventFilter() function must return true if
>   the event should be filtered, (i.e. stopped); otherwise it must return
>   false.